# symfony symlinks and path resolution to src

Tags: php, linux, symfony, unix, symfony1

If you have a setup on your server such as:

```
/path/sites/site1
  app/
  bin/
  web/
  src/
  vendor/ -> /path/vendor/Symfony_2.0.3/vendor (symbolic links)
/path/sites/site2
  app/
  bin/
  web/
  src/
  vendor/ -> /path/vendor/Symfony_2.0.3/vendor (symbolic links)
/path/vendor/Symfony_2.0.3/vendor
```

How does then symfony know where to find the src folder etc?

As **__DIR__** etc in php will resolve the /path/sites/site2/vendor to the actual real path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through reflection!

Symfony 1.x

```
sfProjectConfiguration.class.php

static public function guessRootDir()
{
    $r = new ReflectionClass('ProjectConfiguration');

    return realpath(dirname($r->getFileName()).'/..');
}
```

Symfony 2

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel

```
public function getRootDir()
{
    if (null === $this->rootDir) {
        $r = new \ReflectionObject($this);
        $this->rootDir = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($r->getFileName()));
    }

    return $this->rootDir;
}
```